# Powershell file rename issue

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rename a file for yesterday's date using the code below and stuck on a very small issue.

Code:

```
powershell $a = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd'); Rename-Item RecLoad.htm $a.htm;
```

Error:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is null. At line:1 char:62 + $a = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd'); Rename-Item  <<<< RecLoad.htm $a.htm;
```

If I use a special character before the `$a` variable e.g. `_$a.htm` it works fine but includes the character in front of the filename.

Please help.

**Edit 1**: `Rename-Item RecLoad.htm $a'.htm';` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your strings in quotations to make sure they actually evaluate to strings.  Double quoted strings will still evaluate variables.  For example:

```
PS C:\> $test = $a.htm
PS C:\> $test                                         # Evaluates to null

PS C:\> $test2 = "$a.htm"
PS C:\> $test2                                        # Evaluates to 20140930.htm
```

So just update your line so that:

```
Rename-Item "RecLoad.html" "$a.htm"
```

Comment: Changed to `Rename-Item "RecLoad.htm" "$a.htm";` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Curious... that fixed it when I ran it locally.

Comment: And using `Rename-Item RecLoad.htm $a'.htm';` worked for me. Sigh!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it looks like you are trying to get the property `htm` from the variable `$a`. Since there is no such property of `$a` null is returned. `$a` in this case is a basic string and not a complex object.

Not sure why it did not work for you but simply wrapping it in quotes should have worked. It would expand `a$` as part of the string and ignore `.htm` as simple text. This "feature" can cause issues where someone would actually want to get parameters of a variable. In you case it should work to your advantage.

```
"$a.htm"
```

Mayhaps something like this would be a substitute. Using the [`-f`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) format parameter we get the value of $a and insert it into postion 0 marked by `{0}`. It should be in brackets as part of the cmdlet `Rename-Item`

```
Rename-Item -Path RecLoad.htm -NewName ("{0}.htm" -f $a)
```

Comment: Even `Rename-Item -Path RecLoad.htm -NewName ("{0}.htm" -f $a)` didn't work. So far only the one in my **Edit 1** is working. TIL Mayhaps is a word. Thanks.